# How to keep name attribute in a template form using django widget tweaks?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-widget-tweaks

I have created a form in a template in my Django project. Using Django widget tweaks, I customize my template form and now i wanted to add an attribute name = "Total" in my customized form.

Html code:

```
{% render_field  form.amount placeholder=form.amount.label  class="stylefordate" name="total" %}
```

When I tried this, I couldn't able to get the value of name. Can someone please help me doing this?

Comment: What do you mean by "not able to get the value of name"? What is the HTML generated by the tag?

Comment: Actually, I wanted to refer that field as total, and I also assigned two other fields as 'a' & 'b'. So, when i enters the values in 'a' & 'b', 'total' will be the multiplication of a & b. Finally, I am trying to store the total in my template form to use it for the future purpose. Here's my code:
<input type="text" name="first" placeholder="number"> 
<input type="text" name="second" placeholder="Amount"> 
{% render_field  form.amount placeholder=form.amount.label  class="form-control" name="total" %}

Comment: But when i am entering a & b, i couldn't able to get total value. When i am doing this with <input type="text" name="total"> , total value is returning. 
Can u please help me in doing this with {%render_field%}